How to alter the 'Promoted to front page' label on the node edit form?
How can I alter the 'Promoted to front page' label on the node edit form? I tried:
/**
 * Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function my_module_form_node_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) : void {
  $form['promote']['widget']['#title'] = 'Featured';
}

...but this did not work.

The title for the Promote to front page checkbox is stored in $form['promote']['widget']['value']['#title'].
To change it, you need to use this code.
/**
 * Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id): void {
  $form['promote']['widget']['value']['#title'] = t('Featured');
}


Since Drupal 8 base fields defined in code can be overridden in config. You can add such a config object as yaml file:
core.base_field_override.node.article.promote.yml
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - node.type.article
id: node.article.promote
field_name: promote
entity_type: node
bundle: article
label: 'Display on front page'
description: ''
required: false
translatable: true
default_value:
  -
    value: 1
default_value_callback: ''
settings:
  on_label: 'On'
  off_label: 'Off'
field_type: boolean

Or use a contrib module to create it in the admin UI:
Base Field Override UI

The Base Field Override UI
module enables an interface to be able to change the labels and
descriptions of the fields that have been created by code using the
BaseFieldDefinition class (Example, the title field of the node
entity).

The resulting config can be deployed without the module.

Use the "String overrides" configuration in settings.php.
